# Order of a group whose elements have the same order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group such that every element has the same order $p$. Then I must prove that $p$ is a prime number. I know Lagrange's, Cauchy's, the "counting" formulas, etc., but they seem to not be useful to prove this claim.

We can write that $\#G = m \cdot p$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. I can see that we can write $G$ as the disjoint union of powers of some subset $\{g_1,...,g_m\}$ with $g_i \in G$.

Can you help me with some clever way to think of the problem?

Comment: Hint: if $G$ is cyclic of order $n$ and $d|n$ then there is a subgroup of $G$ of order $d$.

Comment: Every finite group has an element of order $p$ whenever $p$ is prime and divides the group order. If $p$ were composite , there would be no element with prime order , contradiction. Strictly speaking, we have to rule out the trivial group being a counterexample.

Comment: @Math_Images_Only what was the name of that theorem? Or was it a corollary of some other? And thanks, I can see how the claim follows from it.

Comment: This is wrong. The hypothesis implies that $p=1$, which is not a prime number.

Comment: @Sarah there isn't really a name to the theorem. I holds more generally for finite abelian groups. It is also quite easy to see for cyclic groups since given a generator $g$ of $G$ the element $g^{d|n}$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order $d$ in $G$

Comment: @DerekHolt It's for every $g \neq e$.

Comment: @Sarah But it's still wrong when $G$ is trivial!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you should assume that:

- $G$ is non-trivial.
- Every *non-identity* element in $G$ has the same order $p$.

Then you can prove that $p$ must be a prime. You could use Cauchy's theorem as in the other answer, but it's not necessary.

Instead prove the following:

> Every non-trivial finite group has an element of prime order.

Note that is not the same as Cauchy's theorem, and the proof is much easier.

Just use that fact that if $g$ has order $n > 1$ and $k \mid n$, then $g^{n/k}$ has order $k$.